# Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, chained-assignment

I'd like to replace values in a `Pandas` `DataFrame` larger than an arbitrary number (100 in this case) with `NaN` (as values this large are indicative of a failed experiment). Previously I've used this to replace unwanted values:

```
sve2_all[sve2_all[' Hgtot ng/l'] > 100] = np.nan
```

However, I got the following error:

```
-c:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:346: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
self.obj[item] = s
```

From [this StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-this-pandas-warning), it seems that sometimes this warning can be ignored, but I can't follow the discussion well enough to be certain whether this applies to my situation. Is the warning basically letting me know that I'll be overwriting some of the values in my `DataFrame`?

Edit: As far as I can tell, everything behaved as it should. As a follow up is my method of replacing values non-standard? Is there a better way to replace values?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As suggested in the error message, you should use loc to do this:

```
sve2_all.loc[sve2_all['Hgtot ng/l'] > 100] = np.nan
```

*The warning is here to stop you modifying a copy (here `sve2_all[sve2_all[' Hgtot ng/l'] > 100]` is **potentially** a copy, and if it is then any modifications would not change the original frame. It could be that it works correctly in some cases but pandas cannot guarantee it will work in all cases... use at your own risk (consider yourself warned! ;) ).*

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this warning while trying to reset the contents of an entire DataFrame but couldn't resolve it using `loc` or `iloc`:

```
df.loc[:, :] = new_values # SettingWithCopyWarning
df.iloc[:, :] = new_values # SettingWithCopyWarning
```

But resolving to the ndarray contained as data solved the problem:

```
df.values[:, :] = new_values # no warnings and desired behavior
```

Comment: I used the same to replace a single column, for df.loc I got this warning too.

Answer (score 3):

---Problem solved for me---

I had that warring error when i tried to convert float --> int even if i used the ".loc" command. my mistake was that i filtered my dataFrame (with masks) before the operation so the conversion occurred in only a small part of the dataframe item/column, the result was a mixed type column wich create a confuison. i solved the problem by converting the data frame before the masks (data filtration), i hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

As it is suggested by other users, you can try:

```
myindex = sve2_all[' Hgtot ng/l'] > 100

sve2_all.loc[myindex, 'yourcolumn'] = np.nan
```

Keep in mind that if you run into problems creating pivot tables (pivot_table `row` keyword not supported by `pandas 0.16.0 #417`) you should use the new syntax of index and columns instead of rows and cols. https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/417

See also:

[Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724378/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: You can check if there is True value in index and then apply replacement
    if (myindex==True).sum()>0:
        df_train.loc[myindex, c] = 0