# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, chained-assignment

Python 3.4 and Pandas 0.15.0

df is a dataframe and col1 is a column. With the code below, I'm checking for the presence of the value 10 and replacing such values with 1000.

```
df.col1[df.col1 == 10] = 1000
```

Here's another example. This time, I'm changing values in col2 based on index.

```
df.col2[df.index == 151] = 500
```

Both these produce the warning below:

```
-c:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Finally,

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(some_function)
```

This produces a similar warning, with an added suggestion:

```
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I'm not sure I understand the discussion pointed to in the warnings. What would be a better way to write these three lines of code?

Note that the operations worked.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The issue here is that: `df.col1[df.col1 == 10]` returns a copy.

So I would say:

```
row_index = df.col1 == 10
# then with the form .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer]
df.loc[row_index, 'col1'] = 100
```

Comment: Thanks. Should be df.loc[row_index, 'col1'] = 100, right?

Comment: @asif.m are are of course 100% correct. I'll fix it

Comment: What do you suggest I do for the third example (with "applymap")?

Comment: @asif.m I need a runnable example that uses `applymap` to assist further.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed with Paul about 'loc' usage.

For your applymap case you should be able to do this:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df.loc[:, cols] = df[cols].applymap(some_function)
```

Comment: That gives the same warning. But this one doesn't: df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].applymap(some_function)

Comment: Interesting.  I'm using pandas 0.15.0 but Python 2.7.5 so didn't test with your environment.  My suggestion does not throw the warning for me.  Good to know that your latter attempt worked

Comment: I'm getting the copy warning even though I'm using .loc:     col_pct = ['Cash', 'Funds']
    ui_df.loc[:, col_pct] = ui_df.loc[:, col_pct].applymap('{0:.2f}%'.format)