# Pandas Setting with copy warning

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to slice a dataframe in pandas and save it to another dataframe. Let's say `df` is an existing dataframe and I want to slice a certain section of it into `df1`. However, I am getting this warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:25: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I have checked various posts in SO discussing the similar issue (two of them are following):

1. [Setting with copy warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724378/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)
2. [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Going through these links, I was able to find issue in following line

```
   Years=['2010','2011']
   for key in Years:
        df1['GG'][key]=df[key][df[key].Consumption_Category=='GG']
```

which I then changed to following

```
   Years=['2010','2011']
   for key in Years:
        df1['GG'][key]=df[key].loc[df['2010'].iloc[:,0]=='GG']
```

and get away with the warning.

However, when I included another line to drop a certain column from this dataframe, I again this got warning which I am unable to dort out.

```
   Years=['2010','2011']
   for key in Years:
        df1['GG'][key]=df[key].loc[df['2010'].iloc[:,0]=='GG']
        df1['GG'][key]=df1['GG'][key].drop(['Consumption_Category'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: I leave it here for people with similar problems, as it helps finding such problems way faster:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373927/get-traceback-of-warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after lot of research and going through pandas documentation, I found the answer to my question. The warning which I was getting is because I have put `inplace=True` in the drop() function. So, I removed the `inplace=True` and saved the result into new datafrmae. Now I do not get any warning.

```
   Years=['2010','2011']
   for key in Years:
        df1['GG'][key]=df[key].loc[df['2010'].iloc[:,0]=='GG']
        df1['GG'][key]=df1['GG'][key].drop(['Consumption_Category'],axis=1)
```