# unexpected SettingWithCopyWarning with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, warnings

I wrote this code to replace the nan values by the median of each column according to the value of the variable to explain:

```
data_target1 = data[data['target'] == 1]
data_target0 = data[data['target'] == 0]
for col_name in data.columns.values: 
        data_target1.loc[:,col_name] = data_target1[col_name].fillna(data_target1[col_name].median())
        data_target0.loc[:,col_name] = data_target0[col_name].fillna(data_target0[col_name].median())

data = pd.concat([data_vae1,data_vae0], ignore_index=True)
data = data.sort_values(by='IDCLI_CALCULE')
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
return data
```

I get during the execution :

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

I understand the warning, I have read the documentation and yet I can't write a code without the warning appearing... Could someone explain my mistake and give me a solution to solve this problem?

I read these 2 pages and I understood that I had to use.loc to solve my problem but I remain blocked...

1- : [Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002762/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)

2- : [Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724378/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)

It's probably a detail but I can't find the key to solve this little problem.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

After verification I was able to solve my problem using the "copy" method as suggested in the commentary.

Comment: Do `data[data['target'] == 1].copy()` when defining the `_target` DataFrames

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible but can you just explain a bit why the warning is fired ? Cause I don't realy see where is m'y mistake ! Thanks !